# trying to submit form and calling .php file

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a form that has an action that is a .php file and a method post.
but when i submit with a submit type button; all that happens is that the entire .php file is shown in the browser..

Seems like nothing inside it is being done it is just being showed?

any ideas to why this might be?

update:

Ok so I've checked and PHP is running on my db server. Now I'm really lost.

Then what can it possibly be?

```
enter code here<?php
$server = "*****";
$user = "******";
$password = "*******";
$db ="********";

$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password) or die(mysql_error());

echo("forbundet til server");

mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());

echo("forbundet til database");

$sql="INSERT INTO lejrskole1 (navn, postnummer)
VALUES
('$_POST[skole]','$_POST[postnummer]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

is the code.

Comment: can you post the code.  do you have opening <?php and closing ?> php brackets?

Comment: Your server has not been configured to invoke PHP to handle .php files.

Comment: Yes it is in brackets everything in the file should be fine. 
Any ideas as how to make the server handle .php files then? shouldn't this be fairly standard?

Comment: Since you're a beginner, use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/). Actually, even if you're not a beginner use XAMPP. Everything's configured for you already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is interpreting the PHP as either text or HTML, but the PHP should never reach the browser.

Since PHP (in this context) is a server side programming language: you must access the PHP program **through a web server** that **supports PHP** and is configured to use it for that file.

If you have a webserver, then you'll need to install a PHP module for it. If you don't, then you'll need to install one first. WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP will provide bundles for Windows or Mac. Almost any Linux or BSD distro will have it in their package management system already.

Comment: I am using Chrome? shouldn't that be fine for interpreting it?

Comment: Chrome is a web browser (which is a client), not a web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your PHP script on a Windows computer, you need to manually install PHP. Once it is installed your browser should run your PHP programs directly from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have a server installed. Try installing XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html and ensure it runs through there. You'll have to access files using http:// (like normal websites) not file://

vikastyagi87 posted just before me. You need to make sure that a web server application (such as Apache) is installed too, php on its own is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing the page? I am guessing that you don't use a web server, so it is impossible to render a .php file. Try installing a web server like [xampp](http://xampp.en.softonic.com/) or [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for Windows, or [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) for Mac.

Comment: I am using surftown, and I've tried using .php files to uplaod stuff to one of their websites before. So I'm pretty sure it's not that my computer doesn't have php installed. But I don't know how to "activate" php on their sever